# exclude container from google monitoring alert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

is there any way to exclude some container from trigger the alert on google monitoring ?

this is the MQL query, i want to exclude some container on namespace stag for trigger the uptime alert

```
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'kubernetes.io/container/uptime'
| filter (resource.namespace_name == 'stag')
| group_by 1m, [value_uptime_mean: mean(value.uptime)]
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.container_name],
    [value_uptime_mean_aggregate: aggregate(value_uptime_mean)]
| absent_for 600s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude some container on namespace stag for trigger the uptime alert then instead of metrics explorer you have to create alerting policy and there you have to add filter as per your needs as follows:

```
Add filter-> namespace_name  =  ”name of your namespace”
Add filter-> Container_name != “name of your container”
```

Through MQL, you can also create the alerting based on your requirements. Please modify your mql query and add

```
(resource.container_name != 'name of container'
     && resource.namespace_name == 'name of namespace')
```

Please refer to the documents for details on [alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#types-of-policies) and [steps to create alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui)

[image]
[image]

Comment: working good thank you